# Update Calculator/Spotlight Currency Conversion

Tags: spotlight

I understand that Spotlight uses Calculator for currency conversion.

I noticed that the conversation rate in Spotlight was inaccurate. It was showing the rate from at least 6 months ago. When I tried testing the conversion in the Calculator app itself, I discovered that trying to do currency conversion specifically crashes the app. Other conversions work fine.

I can't quite figure out how to update/reinstall the Calculator app, let alone fix this issue.

OSX 10.13.6

Crash log, but there doesn't seem to be much useful information here.
[image]

Comment: What OS are you running? You can't update or install Calculator independently of the whole OS. You may be able to restore it from your backup, but it's unlikely that the app itself has been changed or is at fault. I regularly do conversional using Calculator on many different OS versions, so the fault must lie somewhere else. Can you post the crash log?

Comment: @benwiggy I added the crashlog screenshot to the question, but there doesn't seem to be any useful information there.